# I tried to validate a date in laravel, only if the "One_way" checkbox is checked. But it shows error msg even it is selected

Tags: laravel, validation

My code is,

```
return [
    'One_way'=> 'boolean',
    'return_date' => 'required_if:One_Way,0'
]
```

if I wrote,

```
return [
    'One_way'=> 'boolean',
    'return_date' => 'required_if:One_Way,0|date'
]
```

It shows date error msg even the "One_way" is checked.  Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

due the case sensitive:
so change One_Way to One_way will work

```
return[ 'One_way'=> 'boolean', 'return_date' => 'required_if:One_way,0|date', ]
```